# not able to "logOut" with passportjs in expressjs 4

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I use basic auth on my sample app

```
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
    function (userid, password, done) {
        if (userid !== "foo" && passport !== "bar") {
            return done(null, false);
        } else {
            return done(null, {
                userId: "foo"
            });
        }
    })
);
```

And have authentication on one route only

```
app.use(
    "/admin",
    passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }),
    require("./admin"));
```

Inside admin.js, I have a logout route

```
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logOut();
    res.send("Goodbye!");
});
```

was expecting when i call http://localhost:3000/admin/logout, auth session will be terminated. however, even after logout, i can still browse route "/admin"

Any idea what did i miss?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configure your session in next order:

```
app.use(session({ 
  secret: 'your secret',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Then make sure you eliminate the session:

```
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  req.session.destroy();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Make sure you invoke logout instead logOut.